# ADD command to button in kivy .kv file

Tags: file, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language, python-3.8

I need a code example of how to add a command in a button in kivy, I'm using a .kv file can anyone help.
kv file

```
<MyLayout>
BoxLayout:
    orientation:"horizontal"
    size: root.width, root.height
    Button:
        text:"hello"
```

python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyLayout(Widget,App):
     pass
class UiApp(App):
    def build(self):
         return MyLayout()
UiApp().run()
```

I heard of the `on_press` function in kivy but can you guys tell me how to use it in a .kv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple example where the console will print "hello world" when you press the button.
The root.print_hello_world() will activate the function that you defined in your .py file.

**.kv file**

```
<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"horizontal"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            text:"hello"
            on_press:
                root.print_hello_world()
```

**.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyLayout(Widget, App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def print_hello_world(self):
        print("Hello world")     

class UiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

UiApp().run()
```

Comment: i don't actually want this can you instead of a print("hello world") can you add a Label in kivy or Button.